# using LINQ and reflection to get static readonly field values fails

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I am getting some static readonly field values using reflection like this

```
FieldInfo[] allUnits =
    new Unit().GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

and then I successfully get a single field value like this

```
Unit v = (Unit)allUnits[0].GetValue(null);
Console.WriteLine(v.Symbol.StartsWith("e"));
```

and it also prints "True"
So why does this LINQ query to get multiple likewise field values like this...

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fis2 =
    from fi in allUnits
    where ((Unit)fi.GetValue(null)).Symbol.StartsWith("e")
    select fi;
```

...fail and produce an empty result set?

The exception I get is `System.SystemException: specified cast is not valid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that the type of one of the values returned by `fi.GetValue(null)` is not in fact of type `Unit`; You'd be safe to do a check on the type, anyway using another clause such as `fi.FieldType == typeof(Unit)`, or something similar, such that:

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fieldInfos =
    from field in fields
    where field.FieldType == typeof(Unit) && 
      ((Unit)field.GetValue(null)).Symbol.StartsWith("e")
    select field;
```

Answer (score 1):

Grant's solution can also be written as

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fieldInfos = fields
    .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
    .OfType<Unit>()
    .Where(u => u.Symbol.StartsWith("e"));
```